# How to correctly attach a file to POST request in test environment

Tags: csv, go, post, file-upload

I found a few similar questions to this one, but their implementations are not working for me and I'm wondering if it's something about my test environment or if I'm just doing something incorrectly.

Here's how I'm attaching the file in my test request:

```
    file := new(bytes.Buffer)

    f, err := os.Open("myfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, file)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/upload", file)
```

I got an error: `"http: no such file"`

When I get to the line that has `file, _, err := r.FormFile("file")` in the controller.

I also wondered if "file" is the wrong key for FormFile so I also tried "fileupload" and it's the same. A little confused on that.

So I also tried to just build the "csv" on the fly with a csv.NewWriter and it came to a similar result.

Again, the route works great with a postman request that is just about identical, but for some reason I can't get it working for my test.

---

Update: here is more of the test for clarity on how I serve the request. Thanks to Flimzy's comment, I have removed io.Copy and I've now progressed to a new error as well:

```
    f, err := os.Open("myfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    mw := multipart.NewWriter(f)
    mw.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/upload", f)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())

    // add the discountID URL var
    req = mux.SetURLVars(req, map[string]string{
        "discountID": discountID,
    })

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()

    controller := generateDiscountsController()

    // Set middleware memberInfo context
    gContext.Set(req, "memberInfo", memberInfo)

    // Pass appropriate controller method to http handler in this case
    // Get discount
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(controller.ImportCSV)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    resp := response.GetBodyMessage(rr.Body)

    assert.Equal(t, 201, rr.Code)
    assert.Equal(t, "success", resp)
```

error: `"multipart: NextPart: EOF"` this one catches earlier in my controller on `err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)`

---

In my controller the request is handled here:

```
func (d *APIDiscount) ImportCSV(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var firstTen [][]string
    var columns []string

    defer buf.Reset()

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    // using csv writer is safer and better at catching errors than io.Copy
    csvData := csv.NewWriter(&buf)
    memberInfo := gContext.Get(r, "memberInfo").(*entity.MemberInfo)

    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20) // max 32 MB <-- Catching here in the test, but not when I send the request through postman on my local server with the same file
    if err != nil {
        response.InternalError.Send(w, r, memberInfo, 400)
    }

    file, _, err := r.FormFile("file") // <-- Used to catch here when I used io.Copy
    if err != nil {
        if err == http.ErrMissingFile {
            response.MissingFile.Send(w, r, memberInfo, 400)
            return
        }
        response.FileNotAccepted.Send(w, r, memberInfo, 400)
        return
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Forget the `io.Copy` bit. Just pass `f` directly to the `NewRequest` function. There's no need to suck the file into memory first.

Comment: But to answer your question:  _Where_ do you get that error? If you get `no such file`, it probably means that `myfile.csv` doesn't exist. But with the `http: ` prefix, it's very unclear. Is the error occurring after you call `http.Do()`?

Comment: @Flimzy Oh ok, I will not use copy then. It should catch on the error if it does not find the file. I tested to make sure a non-existent file path would trigger an err earlier and it does so I think it is finding the file. I don't call http.Do. I use httptest.NewRecorder(), http.HandlerFunc(), and handler.ServeHTTP(recorder, req). I will update in the question so you can see more of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the updated info. Now I'm confused about the multipart error. I don't see any call to `r.ParseMultipartForm` in your example. Is that a second question?

Comment: Create a file part in `mw`, copy the file to the part and then close the writer.

Comment: @Flimzy , that happens in the controller that handler is calling, but it doesn't happen when I send the same file via a postman request so I'm not sure what's wrong with the attachment. Let me post that too just in case it helps. Thank you for your help.

Comment: multipart.NewWriter(f) creates a writer that writes a multipart form to f. It does not create a form containing the contents of f. See [Writer.CreateFormFile](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Writer.CreateFormFile).